# Perl program for tabulation

Tags: regex, perl

**F1.txt**

```
tom
x
a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4 e=5 
y
b=11 r=12
bob

a=6 b=7 c=8 e=10
```

***result***

**F2.txt**

```
.            X         Y
name  a  b  c  d  e  b   r

tom   1  2  3  4  5  11  12

bob   6  7  8  -  10 -   -
```

Can you kindly help me in this problem of mine?  I have a file F1.txt.  My job is to convert that file into a format as shown in example F2.txt.  I tried doing this by deleting all string values after Tom and Bob except the numerical values in F1.txt, and then concatenate.  Here is the code:

```
use strict;

open (file100,"< data.txt");
open (file101,">>F3.txt");

my @array = < file100>;

print file101 "name    a    b      c      d     e\n\n";
print file101 "tom @array[1]\n\n";
print file101 "bob @array[3]\n\n";
```

Here data.txt:

```
tom

1 2 3 4 5

bob 

6 7 8 10
```

The output that I am getting with this code is:

F3.txt

```
name  a  b  c  d  e

tom   1  2  3  4  5

bob   6  7  8  10
```

The expected output should be like showed in F2.txt but not like F3.txt

Comment: You can't change the input data for your program to work. You have to write a program to take the input as is and give you results. I am sure your teacher would not be happy.

Comment: No it is just a portion of the work that I am supposed to do.Thank you

Comment: @Hameed: The input file i.e. F1.txt itself is output of a file which i want to transform according to my requirement. So i think thats fine.  Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $pr = "%-12s";
my @headers = qw/name a b c d e/;
my %names;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/^\s+//g;
    s/\s+$//g;
    my $line = <DATA>;
    $line =~ s/^\s+//g;
    $line =~ s/\s+$//g;
    %{$names{$_}} = split /\s*=\s*|\s+/, $line;
}

printf $pr x @headers . "\n", @headers;
for (keys %names) {
    my @ds = ($_);
    for my $k (@headers[1..$#headers])
    {
        my $v = $names{$_}->{$k};
        push @ds, $v ? $v : '-';
    }
    printf $pr x @ds . "\n", @ds;
}

__DATA__
 tom
 a = 10.1 b = 2 c = 300.89 d=4145 e=55
bobby
 a= 60 b = 74.2 c = 8 e = 10.25
```

output:

```
name    a       b       c       d       e       
tom     1       2       3       4       5       
bob     6       7       8       -       10
```

Comment: can this code be modified such that it even works when the spaces in DATA.txt is not proper like.. **tom a=1b=2 c=3 d= 4 e=5 bob a=6 b=7 c =8 e = 10**

Comment: ,I would like to ask you that is it possible to print all values corresponding to a key irrespective if the key is repeated twice with different values.The problem that I am facing now is that it takes only the last key-value pair and prints it in the other key names if the two keys have same name.Like as the modified question which i have posted

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
my @names;

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  if (/=/) {
    %{ $data{$names[-1]} } = /[^\s=]+/g;
  }
  else {
    push @names, /(\S+)/;
  }
}

my %keys = map %$_, values %data;
my @keys = sort keys %keys;

printf "%-6s %s\n\n", 'name', join '  ', @keys;
printf "%-6s %s\n\n", $_, join '  ', map $_ // '-', @{$data{$_}}{@keys} for @names;

__DATA__
tom

a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4 e=5

bob

a=6 b=7 c=8 e=10
```

**output**

```
name   a  b  c  d  e

tom    1  2  3  4  5

bob    6  7  8  -  10
```

**Update**

For older versions (before v5.10) Perl will see the defined-or operator `//` as a misplaced regular expression match. For these platforms the second `printf` statement can be written like this

```
printf "%-6s %s\n\n", $_, join '  ', map { defined $_ ? $_ : '-' } @{$data{$_}}{@keys} for @names;
```

Comment: @Borodin I tried this code of urs but its giving me an error "Search pattern not terminated at line 20" what might be the reason. How to correct that

Comment: @unkaitha: You have a very old copy of perl installed. The defined-or operator `//` was introduced in Perl v5.10 in 2007, so anything older than that will cause a compilation error. You should upgrade your perl installation as a priority, but I have added an interim solution to my answer above

Answer (score 1):

For your understanding I am taking a long cut with this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my @vals;
my $key;
my $val;
my $name;
my @headings;
my $file100;

open ($file100, "<", "data.txt");


while (<$file100>)
{
        chomp;
        next if (! m/\S/);
        if (m/=/)
        {
            @vals = $_ =~  /(.+)=(.+)\b/g;
            while (@vals)
            {
                $key = shift @vals;
                if (!grep(/^$key$/, @headings))
                {
                    push (@headings, $key);
                }

                $val = shift @vals;
                $hash{$name}{$key} = $val;
            }
        } else {
           $name = $_;
}

print "name\t" . join ("\t", @headings) . "\n\n";
for my $key1 (keys %hash)
{
    print $key1;
    for (@headings)
    {
        if (defined $hash{$key1}{$_})
        {
            print "\t" . $hash{$key1}{$_};
        } else
        {
            print "\t-";
        }
    }
    print "\n\n";
}
```

**You need to pick up a Perl book and study it.**

Comment: I have just given a sample of a huge file with varying names. so i will not be able to use just the name (tom,bob) and try to modify the input file. any ways thank you for the code , will surely read some books regarding the lines used in your code to understand it.